# Hashmap behaves differently upon remove() and put() while iterating through Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I was trying to understand hashmap better, I looked into the code and the possibilities. When this came to me

```
//HashMap
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("1", "1");
myMap.put("2", "1");
myMap.put("3", "1");
System.out.println("HashMap before iterator: " + myMap);

for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
    if(key.equals("3")) {
        myMap.put(key + "new", "new3");
        myMap.remove("2");      
    }
};

for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
    if(key.equals("3")) {
        myMap.put(key + "new", "new3");
        break;  
    }
};
System.out.println("HashMap after iterator: " + myMap);
```

***Output of this is***

```
HashMap before iterator: {1=1, 2=1, 3=1}
HashMap after iterator: {1=1, 3=1, 3new=new3}
```

The iterator is fail-fast in hashmap, then how is it able to accommodate this changes. Upon this, I came to know that there is a counter which checks the size of the hashmap and throws the exception when the size doesn't match in ***next()***.

What I don't get is how breaking the loop avoid the call for next() at the right moment to skip the check. I even looked at the code of the iterator HashIterator 
I coudnt figure hoe does next() doesnt call for when the code hits ***break;***

And why this code doesn't throw an error.

```
        //HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("1", "1");
    myMap.put("2", "1");
    myMap.put("3", "1");
    System.out.println("HashMap before iterator: "+myMap);

    for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
        if(key.equals("3")) 
            myMap.remove("2");      
    };

    System.out.println("HashMap  after iterator: " + myMap);

    for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
        if(key.equals("3")) 
            myMap.put(key + "new", "new3");
    };

    System.out.println("HashMap  after iterator: " + myMap);
```

Please help me understand this better.

Comment: It seems like your missing `}` for your if statements, is this intentional?

Comment: @Ferrybig He's not, it's just very weird indentation.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation made the required changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `HashIterator` checks the `modCount` in `next()`, but doesn't check it in `hasNext()`:

```
    public final boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    final Node<K,V> nextNode() {
        Node<K,V>[] t;
        Node<K,V> e = next;
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if ((next = (current = e).next) == null && (t = table) != null) {
            do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
        }
        return e;
    }
```

Since you are making a structural change in the `HashMap` in the final iteration of the loop, after that change `hasNext()` returns `false` and `next()` is not called again. Hence no exception.

Note that the iterator created by the enhanced for loop is not aware of the fact that you added an extra `Entry` to the `Map`. Therefore it won't iterate over that extra `Entry`. The fail-fast mechanism can only work if the iterator's `next()` method is called, but as explained earlier, that doesn't happen when you make the change in the final iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yep. Change to the condition to `if (key.equals("2")) {` and it will fail as expected

Comment: Yep, that might be the case for the second hashmap condition. But how is the **_next() and hasNext()_** being called in a way that its effected by break is my actual question

Comment: @user2681668 if you break out of the loop, neither `hasNext()` nor `next()` should be called. The loop just ends prematurely.

Comment: @user2681668 BTW, even without that break statement there will be no exception, since you are putting an existing key in the Map, and therefore causing no structural changes. However, with the break statement, even if you put a different key, there will be no exception.

Comment: `//HashMap
  HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

  myMap.put("1", "1");

  myMap.put("2", "1");

  myMap.put("3", "1");
  System.out.println("HashMap before iterator: "+myMap);

  for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
   if(key.equals("3")) {
    myMap.put(key + "new", "new3");
    myMap.put(key + "new1", "new3");
    myMap.put(key + "new2", "new3");
   }
  };
  
  System.out.println("HashMap  after iterator: " + myMap)

`
Sorry for the bad formatting, I tried but couldn't get it right.
Look at this code there are structural changes, but it still works.

Comment: @user2681668 I added a paragraph to my answer. The reason it works is the same reason - you are making the change in the last iteration of the loop. The iterator doesn't know about the new entries you added.

Comment: I Got it now, the error is thrown only while Iterating through the loop and the loop continues to the next call, any changes that break the iteration just after the change it wont cause the exception.